# Writing function inside dependency injector

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am new to angularjs. I see that people write code like below

```
angular.module('phonecat', ['dotjem.routing']).
  config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
      .state('phones', { views: { 'main': { template: 'phones.html' } })
      .state('tablets', { views: { 'main': { template: 'tablets.html' } });
}]);
```

I understand that [] is for injecting dependencies. I know that we are injecting $stateProvider. But whats the use of writing the second parameter i.e. the function. Is is just syntax and serve any specific purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a string literal. The sole purpose of this is to avoid problems with minification and/or obfuscation. The string would survive that.

From there, they just match up with the *actual* function arguments 1-to-1. You could name the `$stateProvider` anything you want at this point. As long as the string matches the actual name of the service. The only important thing is that they are in the right order.

This code would work fine:

```
angular.module('phonecat', ['dotjem.routing']).
  config(['$stateProvider', function(pizza) {
  pizza
      .state('phones', { views: { 'main': { template: 'phones.html' } })
      .state('tablets', { views: { 'main': { template: 'tablets.html' } });
}]);
```

Comment: @Hacker, always. If you aren't doing it by hand, you should have a build process that takes care of it for you (like `ng-annotate`, gulp/grunt plugins, etc.). Otherwise you can't safely minify your code (which you should always be doing in production).

Comment: So you mean to say writing .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $rootScope,$cookieStore, $sce)  is not preferred mode ?